# Prove for any ideal $J$, $\operatorname{rad} J$ is an ideal of $A$, if $J$ is ideal of $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $A$ be a ring, and let $J$, $K$ be ideals of $A$. The radical of $J$ is the set $$\operatorname{rad}J=\{a \in A:a^n \in J  \text{ for some }  n \in \mathbb{Z}\}.$$ Prove for any ideal $J$, $\operatorname{rad}J$ is an ideal of $A$.

I know that I will start the proof supposing that $a^n \in J$ and $b^m \in J$, and will work to show $(a+b)^{m+n} \in J.$ How would I go about this? and how do I use this to prove the ideal?

Comment: Is $A$ a commutative ring?  I don't believe this is true for general rings.

Comment: Yes A is commutative, your right the property doesn't hold for all rings.

Comment: Please search for your question before posting, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use binomial theorem to expand $(a+b)^{m+n}$ and prove that each $a^{m+n-k}b^k\in J$. Since $J$ is an ideal, the sum is in $J$.